# Evaluating an integral using Stokes' theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**The Question**

Given a curve using the edges of the plane in the first octant $z=1-x-\frac17y$, evaluate

$$\oint_C\textbf F\cdot d\textbf r$$

where $\textbf F=<e^{-x},e^x,e^z>$.

**My Attempt**

Using Stokes' theorem, I obtain

$$\iint_S(\nabla\times\textbf F)\cdot d\textbf S$$

where $\textbf S$ is the surface of the plane in the first octant. I parametrize the plane as $\textbf r=<x,y,1-x-\frac17y>$. Then $d\textbf S=\textbf (\textbf r_x\times\textbf r_y)\,dA$ to find the area of the surface element corresponding to the domain $A$.

I found that $\textrm{curl}\,\textbf F=e^x\textbf k$ and $\textbf r_x\times\textbf r_y=<1,\frac17,1>$. So the integral becomes

$$\iint_De^x\,dA=\int_0^7\int_0^{1-\frac y7}e^x\,dx\,dy=\frac17(e-50)$$

which is wrong, so now I'm troubleshooting my process to find out my mistake.